# Avoiding code duplication for reading in similar values for each derived class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing a program that handles many types of grooves `TKY, VSingle` under `GrooveType`.

Each of this groove is paired with its specific parameter `SimulationParam` (e.g. `TKY` will pair with `SimulationParamTKY`, which inherits from `SimulationParam`) under the `Dictionary simParams`. As such, if i want to include more types of grooves, I can add it under this dictionary.

`SimulationParam` contains `ProcessParam`, which has the parameters `probeStartAngle` and `probeStartDist`. These parameters are similar(in meaning) for both `TKY` and `VSingle`.

However, in the dialog, I want the user to be able to select which particular groove they want. When that particular option is selected, the respective values for `probeStartAngle` and `probeStartDist` is read in from their respective text box. For example, if `Use TKY` is selected, the `ProcessParam.probeStartAngle` value will be read from `tbTKYStartAngle`.

As such, when I extend this program to even more grooves (say 10 more), under `btnProcess_Click()`, a lot of code will actually be repeated.

Is there a better way to write this code to reduce the repetitions? Assuming the requirement is that the textboxes for each groove cannot be merged into a single one. (i.e. meaning i cannot read from the same textbox for say `ProcessParam.probeStartAngle`)

[image]

```
public partial class GrooveDialog : Form
    {
        public enum GrooveType : int
        {
            TKY = 0,
            VSingle = 1,
        }

        Dictionary<GrooveType, SimulationParam> simParams = new Dictionary<GrooveType, SimulationParam>();

        public GrooveDialog()
        {
            simParams.Add(GrooveType.TKY, new SimulationParamTKY());
            simParams.Add(GrooveType.VSingle, new SimulationParamVSingle());
        }

        private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbUseTKY.Checked)
            {
                var simParamTKY = (SimulationParamTKY)simParams[GrooveType.TKY];

                simParamTKY.processParam.probeStartAngle = Convert.ToDouble(tbTKYAngle.Text);
                simParamTKY.processParam.probeStartDist = Convert.ToDouble(tbTKYDist.Text);
            }
            else if (rbUseVSingle.Checked)
            {
                var simParamVSingle = (SimulationParamVSingle)simParams[GrooveType.VSingle];

                simParamVSingle.processParam.probeStartAngle = Convert.ToDouble(tbVSingleAngle.Text);
                simParamVSingle.processParam.probeStartDist = Convert.ToDouble(tbVSingleDist.Text);
            }
    }

public class ProcessParam 
    {
        public ProcessParam() { }
        public double probeStartAngle { get; set; }
        public double probeStartDist { get; set; }
    }

    public class SimulationParam
    {
        public ProcessParam processParam { get; set; }
    }

    public class SimulationParamTKY : SimulationParam
    {
        public double alpha, theta;

        public SimulationParamTKY()
        {
            this.processParam = new ProcessParam();
        }

        public SimulationParamTKY(ProcessParam parameters)
            : this()
        {
            this.processParam = parameters;
        }
    }

    public class SimulationParamVSingle : SimulationParam
    {
        public double deta, eta;

        public SimulationParamVSingle()
        {
            this.processParam = new ProcessParam();
        }

        public SimulationParamVSingle(ProcessParam parameters)
            : this()
        {
            this.processParam = parameters;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just scatching the surface of your code, but

1. By default, the first enum constant has a default value of 0 , so this code

```
       public enum GrooveType : int
            {
                TKY = 0,
                VSingle = 1,
            }
```

could be written as

```
       public enum GrooveType : int
            {
                TKY,
                VSingle
            }
```

2. Your **ProcessParam** was implemented twice. When things like this occur you should change  **ProcessParam** into an abstract class. This is called **Dependency Inversion**

   > **Dependency Inversion**: In object-oriented programming, the dependency inversion principle refers to a specific form of decoupling software modules. When following this principle, the conventional dependency relationships established from high-level, policy-setting modules to low-level, dependency modules are reversed, thus rendering high-level modules independent of the low-level module implementation details. The principle states:[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)
   >
   > - High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.
   > - Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions. More details of this [Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

This line of code should have been

```
public class ProcessParam 
    {
        public ProcessParam() { }
        public double probeStartAngle { get; set; }
        public double probeStartDist { get; set; }
    }
```

should have been

```
abstract class ProcessParam   // Abstract class
{
    public abstract void AbstractMethod();   // Abstract method
    public abstract double probeStartAngle { get; set; }
    public abstract double probeStartDist { get; set; }
}
```

3. **Dependency Injection** : Inject dependency rather than creating an object in the constructor. This is good

   ```
   public SimulationParamVSingle(ProcessParam parameters)
       : this()
   {
       this.processParam = parameters;
   }
   ```

This is bad

```
 public SimulationParamVSingle()
        {
            this.processParam = new ProcessParam();
        }
```